# Speed of writing on HTML5 canvas vs. OneNote

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a fundamental reason why drawing with a stylus on an HTML canvas, using libraries such as [atrament.js](http://fiala.uk/atrament.js/demo/) or [signature_pad](http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/) seems to be a lot slower than drawing on OneNote? There seems to be a night and day difference and I'm trying to figure out of it's a limitation of javascript, or browsers, or something else.

Does anyone have any knowledge if the above solutions are working at the maximum level of performance? And if so, why that theshold is different than OneNote?

Edit: The desktop version of OneNote

Comment: Are you referring to the desktop OneNote program or the web-based OneNote application?

Comment: The desktop version

Answer (score 0):

A browser is event-driven. This means that the following happens: input > processing input > draw to canvas > paint to screen. The browser is locked to 60FPS, so the input can be up to a frame behind: input (0ms) > processing > draw > paint (16ms). Also, if the processing or draw steps are slow, it can get laggy.

Desktop applications are not necessarily limited to 60FPS, and they can draw directly to the screen whenever they like. So the loop can be more like: input > paint.

This is all high-level, but those are the kinds of things that can lead to lag between input and output.

Comment: events are not tied to the screen refresh rate and neither is js. Only the paintings are, but the same applies for desktop apps (they can hardly change the hardware limitation of your screen refresh rate). So what happens really is *loop1 : [event => processing (=> draw to canvas)] ( max(input device rate , processing time))* | *loop 2 : paint (60fps)*. So one common technique is to include *=> draw to canvas*  in *loop2*  to avoid *processing time* to be uselessly too long by doing multiple time something that would be visible only once.

Comment: And actually, in most modern browsers, (all that I tested) events are processed by an different thread than the one executing the js, which means that even if you freeze the page, events are still stored, and processed once the browser can. So it would be *phase1 : [event => UA processing](max rate = input device rate) phase2: [js processing (=> draw to canvas)] (processing time) phase3: paint (max rate = 60fps)*.

Comment: @Kaiido: Sounds about right to me. I did know that stuff, but wanted to keep it simple and high-level (wasn't sure how deep OP is into how this works, from their post). You should put that in an answer, though; maybe it would be chosen instead.

Comment: Well nope, it doesn't explain **why these libs are slower**. So yes they are more high level, but nowadays, it makes really little difference on such a simple application as an *listen to input and draw a circle* ; I don't think they eat the input max-rate limit, except if they are badly written, which I don't know, nor really want to.

Comment: Well we don't know what OP is trying to do with it, and what code is being called. It could be the JS libs, it could be the fact the JS is running in the browser which makes it difficult to match C++ efficiency, it could be a DOM issue, OP could be trying to render the mona lisa stroke by stroke. It could be any number of things. I think this is one of those questions that is just a rabbithole and kinda unanswerable. I just thought I'd try to give them some idea of what's involved.